# New Expression Syntax issue

Tags: asp.net, .net

In my asp.net 4.0 page, inside the ItemTemplate in GridView, I have applied New Expression syntax for Binding Columns like

```
<%#: Eval(ColumnName) %>
```

The data is bound successfully in my local machine. After deploying to another server, with Framework 4.0 installed I receive following error

**CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'**

against the above Expression. Any solution regarding this ? Anything to be included in Web.Config ?

Comment: I am assuming he wants the functionality of the colon operator.

Comment: @AbeMiessler - He wants the colon to automatically HTML-encode the content.

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that the deployed server's application pool is running `.NET 4.0` and not `.NET 2.0`?

The `:` syntax is only valid in `.NET 4.0` and later.

Here is a sample screenshot from IIS:

[image]

Note: Ignore the lines and text, it was taken from another SO question.

Comment: Yes I have changed to .NET 4.0, but the server which I had deployed is having IIS 6 and Windows Server 2003. Then I deployed to another having IIS 7.5. Same issue occurs.